# Kommt bei "Aber dass" am Satzanfang ein Komma vor "dass"?

Tags: comma

> Aber, dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst, steht fest?

Kommt zwischen "aber" und "dass" ein Komma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kurze Antwort

Offenbar gibt es (mindestens) drei Möglichkeiten, wozu das Wort *aber* gehören könnte, und jede bedingt eine andere Zeichensetzung:

1. *Aber* als Einleitung des Fragesatzes (vgl. die Antwort von @rexkogitans)

   > Aber, dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst, steht fest?
2. *Aber* als Einleitung des Subjektsatzes (vgl. die Antworten von @David Vogt, @The Awful Language und @Loong)

   > Aber dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst, steht fest?
3. *Aber* als Ellipse eines Einwands oder einer Nachfrage

   > Aber: dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst, steht fest?

### Lange Antwort

#### 1. *Aber* als Einleitung des Fragesatzes

Interpretieren wir das Wort *aber* zunächst als Einleitung des Fragesatzes

> Aber *das* steht fest?

Ersetzt man das Denmonstrativpronomen *das* durch den [Subjektsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebensatz#Subjekt-_und_Objekts%C3%A4tze) *„dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst“*, muss der durch Kommas abgetrennt werden (§ 74 des amtlichen Regelwerks):

> Aber, *dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst*, steht fest?

⇒  Bei dieser Interpretation steht nach *aber* ein Komma.

#### 2. *Aber* als Einleitung des Subjektsatzes

Wir können das Wort *aber* auch als Einleitung des Subjektsatzes

> *aber dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst*

interpretieren, bei dem nach *aber* kein Komma folgt (vgl. E1 zu § 74 des amtlichen Regelwerks). Lautet der Fragesatz

> *Das* steht fest?

und ersetzt man des Demonstrativpronomens durch den Subjektsatz, so kommt nur nach *wirst* ein abgrenzendes Komma. Übrigens wäre es ungrammatisch, den Subjektsatz ans Ende zu stellen:

> <s>Steht fest, *aber dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst*?</s>
>
> *Aber dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst*, steht fest?

⇒  Bei dieser Interpretation steht nach *aber* kein Satzzeichen.

#### 3. *Aber* als Ellipse eines Einwands oder einer Nachfrage

Eine weitere Möglichkeit besteht darin, *aber* als Ellipse zu interpretieren, etwa:

> Aber (was ich noch fragen wollte): ...

Dadurch wird der Charakter eines Einwands oder einer Nachfrage betont:

> Aber: *dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst*, steht fest?

⇒  Bei dieser Interpretation steht nach *aber* ein Doppelpunkt.

Comment: Das ist alles richtig, aber warum ist das ein Nebensatz, und welche Funktion hat er?

Comment: Wie verträgt sich 2. mit der Ungrammatikalität von *\*steht fest, aber dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst*?

Comment: Nach deiner Antwort sollten nach 1 und 2 ja aber beide Schreibweisen gehen, oder? Ich verstehe allerdings den semantischen Unterschied zwischen 1 und 2 nicht.

Comment: Genau. Über den semantischen Unterschied der Zugehörigkeit von _aber_ müsste man nochmal nachdenken. Zumindest bei der dritten Variante ist klar, dass sie sich von den anderen beiden unterscheidet.

Comment: Schreibt man in diesem Fall nicht groß nach dem Doppelpunkt?

Answer (score 3):

Dort sollte kein Komma stehen. Die [amtlichen Regeln](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) sind zwar so knapp formuliert, daß es nicht immer leicht ist, zu erkennen, wie sie genau gemeint sind. Aber unter § 74 heißt es:

> Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit
> paarigem Komma ein.

Ein eingeschobener Nebensatz liegt hier aber nicht vor. Wie in den anderen Antworten zurecht betont wird, handelt es sich um einen Subjektsatz. Deshalb gehe ich davon aus, daß ein Komma genügen muß:

> Aber dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst, steht fest?

Ein kurzer Blick in die Praxis bestätigt diesen Eindruck.

> Aber dass es so schnell geht, hat mich dann auch überrascht. ([Quelle](https://www.welt.de/regionales/duesseldorf/article13848433/Horst-Eckert-will-Abgruende-zeigen.html))
>
> Aber dass alles beim Alten bleibt, halte ich für nicht sehr wahrscheinlich. ([Quelle](https://tageswoche.ch/kultur/neue-ideen-fuer-den-kunstkredit/))
>
> Aber dass ausgerechnet der Panda eine signifikante Rolle dabei spielen könnte, dieses Wirrwarr zu entzerren, das wird Sie schockieren. ([Quelle](https://badduerrheim.de/veranstaltungen/uebersicht/kulturforum-lisa-catena/))

Answer (score 2):

Duden Band 9 – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* erklärt hierzu sehr konkret

> Steht *dass* hinter einer nebenordnenden Konjuktion (z. B. *aber, denn, und, oder*), so steht das Komma vor dieser Konjunktion. *Du sagst mir nichts Neues, denn dass sie zugestimmt hat, wusste ich schon gestern.*

In der Ergänzung E 1 zu § 74 des amtlichen Regelwerks findet man eine etwas allgemeinere Regel

> Besteht die Einleitung eines Nebensatzes aus einem Einleitewort und weiteren Wörtern, so gilt:
>
> (1) Man setzt das Komma vor die ganze Wortgruppe:
>
> *Ich habe sie selten besucht, aber wenn ich bei ihr war, saßen wir bis spät in die Nacht zusammen.* …

Diese Regel wird allerdings gleich darauf wieder etwas aufgeweicht:

> (2) In einigen Fällen kann der Schreibende zusätzlich ein Komma zwischen den Bestandteilen der Wortgruppe setzen:
>
> *Morgen wird es regnen, angenommen(,) dass der Wetterbericht stimmt.* …
>
> (3) Der Schreibende kann durch das Komma deutlich machen, ob er Wörter als Bestandteil der Nebensatzeinleitung verstanden wissen will oder nicht:
>
> *Ich freue mich, auch wenn du mir nur eine Karte schreibst. Ich freue mich auch, wenn du mir nur eine Karte schreibst.* …

Answer (score 1):

Der Teil des Satzes mit den Wörtern "dass du dieses oder jenes machen wirst" ist:

1. ein vollständiger Satz: Er hat ein Subjekt (*du*) und ein dazu konjugiertes Verb (*wirst*).
2. das Subjekt zu dem umgebenden Satz: Nach ihm kann mit "wer oder was?" gefragt werden. Er ist also ein *Subjektsatz*.

Deshalb muss er von Beistrichen **umgeben** sein, also muss auch ein Beistrich vor *dass* stehen.

Der Subjektsatz kann durch das einzelne Wort *das* ohne Beistriche ersetzt werden:

> Aber **das** steht fest?

In diesem Fall ist offensichtlich, dass der äußere Satz vollständig ist (der Subjektsatz ist das Subjekt, und *steht fest* ist das konjugierte Verb).

Man könnte den Satz auch umstellen, um den ersten Beistrich völlig zu vermeiden:

> Dass du dieses und jenes machen wirst, steht aber fest?

Anderseits könnte man auch die ganze Wortfolge "Aber dass du dieses oder jenes machst" (umgestellt: *Dass du aber dieses oder jenes machst*) als Subjektsatz betrachten und es durch *das* erseten:

> Das steht aber fest?

In diesem Fall fall gehört zwischen *aber* und *dass* kein Beistrich.

Es ist also beides grammatikalisch korrekt, es entscheidet nur, ob das Wort *aber* zum Subjektsatz gehört oder nicht. Der Unterschied in der Bedeutung ist gering, wenn er überhaupt vorhanden ist.

Comment: Why should *aber* at the beginning of a sentence be ungrammatical?

Comment: @DavidVogt Sure, I dropped the comment with _jedoch_ because it changes the sentence too much.

Answer (score 0):

In der genannten Bedeutung ist das "aber" eine Hauptsatzkonjunktion, aber dass der erste Hauptsatz weggelassen wurde, macht die Konstruktion im Beispiel ungrammatisch.

Siehe vorangehender Satz: ein Komma gehört vor das "aber", keins dahinter.

Comment: _"ein Komma gehört vor das "aber", keins dahinter"_ Oder eher ein Semikolon?

Comment: Eher nein: ein Semikolon kann man verwenden, wenn man zwei gleichgeordnete Sätze stärker als durch Komma, schwächer als durch Punkt trennen will. Durch das "aber" (Adversativkonjunktion) sind die beiden Sätze jedoch nicht gleichgeordnet.